# How can define two dimension string array in android resource?

Tags: android

I wish to fill in a spinner control with MsgName field, and get MsgValue when I select a item of the spinner.
so I write the following code.but I don't think it's a good code, is there the better code? 
Do I need to define two dimension string array for my app? How can I do?  Thanks!

```
<?xmlversion="1.0"encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
 <string-arrayname="MsgName">
   <item>Inbox</item>
   <item>Sent</item>
 </string-array>

 <string-arrayname="MsgValue">
   <item>content://sms/inbox</item>
   <item>content://sms/sent</item>
 </string-array>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would want to explicitly associate each name with it's value, instead of just having them be in the same position in two separate arrays.

There's at least a couple of ways to accomplish this.

- Use some sort of separator to concatenate the name and the value in the same item:
  e.g.:

> <string-array name="message">
>
> <item>Inbox|content://sms/inbox</item>
>
> <item>Sent|content://sms/sent</item>
>
> </string-array>

- Create a custom xml resource, e.g. res/values/message-list.xml:

> <messages>
>
> <message name="Inbox">content://inbox</message>
>
> <message name="Sent">content://sent</message>
>
> </messages>

Of course, either way, you're going to have process the contents and create a SpinnerAdapter - in the first case, you'll have to split the entries, and in the second case, you'll have to parse the xml.

Comment: Thanks!   To Method 1: <item>Inbox|content://sms/inbox</item> Is it easy to fill in these strings with separator to spinner control and is it easy to get the value of the seleceted item?    To Method 2: <message name="Inbox">content://inbox</message> It's hard to make these strings  internationalization, such as you can't translate the word "inbox" to chinese "收件箱"

Comment: Neither of these is particularly difficult. Both are inherently internationalizable, as you can have a different version of the resource (either strings.xml in the first case, or your custom xml in the second case) based on Locale.